# rails group by to make nested table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

I have product and stocks. Each stock contains `product_id, color_id, storage_id and in_stock`.

For a given product I want to group stocks by storage then colors and output in_stock like:

Storage 1

- Storage 1

  - Color A: in_stock
  - Color B: in_stock
- Storage 2:

  - Color A: in_stock
  - Color B: in_stock

Unfortunately I can't render the view.

So far my query is the following:

```
def all_units_in_stock
  stocks.in_stock.group(:storage_id, :color_id).includes(:storage, :color)
end

which returns
Product.find(11).all_units_in_stock
Product Load (37.1ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
Stock Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."product_id" = 11 AND (in_stock > 0) GROUP BY storage_id
Storage Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "storages".* FROM "storages" WHERE "storages"."id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Color Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "colors".* FROM "colors" WHERE "colors"."id" IN (3)
=> [#<Stock id: 162, product_id: 11, storage_id: 1, in_stock: 10.0, created_at: "2011-11-07 22:54:50", updated_at: "2011-11-07 22:54:50", color_id: 3>, #<Stock id: 163, product_id: 11, storage_id: 2, in_stock: 10.0, created_at: "2011-11-07 22:54:50", updated_at: "2011-11-07 22:54:50", color_id: 3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Order by storage, then color.  Then use the group_by function on the results, this will create an ordered hash with the Storage Id as the key.  Because you ordered by storage & color, the ordering will be maintained in the hash.

```
products = Product.find(11).all_units_in_stock
@group_by_storage = products.group_by {|p| p.storage_id }
```

Now in your view you can iterate through the hash.

```
<% @group_by_storage.each do |key, value| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= key %>

      <ul>
        <li><%= value.color_id %>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <ul>
```

Please excuse the erb syntax if in correct, I'm used to HAML markup.